# WPF C# Image Source

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I'm pretty new to displaying images in WPF forms, and i'm having trouble when it comes to converting and assigning an Image source for my GUI.

```
        System.Drawing.Image testImg = ImageServer.DownloadCharacterImage(charID, ImageServer.ImageSize.Size128px);
        byte[] barr = imgToByteArray(testImg);
        CharImage.Source = ByteToImage(barr);          

    public byte[] imgToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image testImg)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            testImg.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public System.Drawing.Image ByteToImage(byte[] barr)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(barr);
        System.Drawing.Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
        return returnImage;
    }
```

So i take in an image (JPEG) from the EVE Online C# API Library and then try to convert it to a byte array and back to a proper image. However i always get this error: "Cannot Implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'" I'm completely dumbfounded on how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Drawing.Image` is WinForms, not WPF. Your ByteToImage method should return `BitmapSource` instead.

The probably easiest way to create a `BitmapSource` from a byte array is `BitmapFrame.Create`:

```
public BitmapSource ByteArrayToImage(byte[] buffer)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
    {
        return BitmapFrame.Create(stream,
            BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
    }
}
```

You would assign the return value of the above method to the `Source` property of an `Image` control:

```
image.Source = ByteArrayToImage(barr);
```

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to save the image files (for example, .`jpg`) as WPF embedded resource and then use the following code snippet to get `BitmapImage`:

*Listing 1. Get BitmapImage from EmbeddedResource*

```
private string GetAssemblyName()
{
    try { return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName.Split(',')[0]; }
    catch { throw; }
}

private BitmapImage GetEmbeddedBitmapImage(string pathImageFileEmbedded)
{
    try
    {
        // compose full path to embedded resource file
        string _fullPath = String.Concat(String.Concat(GetAssemblyName(), "."), pathImageFileEmbedded);

        BitmapImage _bmpImage = new BitmapImage();
        _bmpImage.BeginInit();
        _bmpImage.StreamSource = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(_fullPath);
        _bmpImage.EndInit();
        return _bmpImage;
    }
    catch { throw; }
    finally { }
}
```

Correspondingly, set the `Source` property of the WPF `Image` control (for example, `Image1`) to that `BitmapImage` returned by function:

```
Image1.Source = GetEmbeddedBitmapImage(_strEmbeddedPath);
```

Note: you should reference the following:

```
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Reflection;
```

Another possible solution is to get the `BitmapImage` from image file using `Uri` object as shown in the following code snippet (Listing 2):

*Listing 2. Get BitmapImage from File (use Uri)*

```
private BitmapImage GetBitmapImageFromFile(string ImagePath)
{
    Uri BitmapUri;
    StreamResourceInfo BitmapStreamSourceInfo;
    try
    {
        // Convert stream to Image.
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        BitmapUri = new Uri(ImagePath, UriKind.Relative);
        BitmapStreamSourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(BitmapUri);
        bi.BeginInit();
        bi.StreamSource = BitmapStreamSourceInfo.Stream;
        bi.EndInit();
        return bi;
    }
    catch { throw; }
}
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: So where in this would i be putting the image itself? Sorry pretty new to WPF so I'm Out of my depth here

Comment: Don't forget to set `bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;`, otherwise the image may not be loaded by the time you need to display it. You'd think the framework would know to do this but it's caught me out a few times.

Comment: You should have some Image control placed in XAML Grid and named for example <Image Name="Image1"...> Apply that BitmapImage to its property Image1.Source. Best regards,

Comment: Far better than an *Embedded Resource* is a plain *Resource*. Then you would load a BitmapImage from a [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly) like `new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/Test.jpg"));`